# error accessing function in 64 bit dll

Tags: c++, dll, stack, 64-bit

```
invoke LoadLibraryA, $("64.dll")
invoke GetProcAddress, rax, $("rundll")

call rax
```

I am trying to execute a function in a 64-bit DLL from an EXE. In a debugger, its successful to get a pointer to `rundll`, but fails with an access violation error when called.

What I need to do with the stack to make it work?

Comment: There is no way to answer this since you didn't show the declaration of the `rundll` function. I'm voting to close this as off-topic: "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*"

Answer (score 0):

its work fine if i compile dll as exe. rundll code wihout errors

i was have same problem before and i was adding

```
    sub rsp, 20h
```

before calling

```
    call rax
```

but now its not help me

Comment: rundll have no parameters